# Frequent boot error

Tags: boot

Two times this week my notebook showed this error while booting (I transcript some parts)

```
Hardware error : CPU 0 : Machine check: 0 Bank 4: e600000000
There are more numbers and then
0.210526 mce hardware error : Tsc 0 Addr fef5d340
```

There are more data, and then

```
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/mmcblk1p2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. and so.
```

I repaired it last time using fsck, but don't understand what's happening. I'm using 18.04.4. Thanks.

Comment: Are you in a root or BusyBox shell? Unmount the said drive a run `fsck \dev\<>` on it. The first part of your message indicates a faulty hardware. Most modern pcs have the ability to test hardware from boot menu. Try to run that or memtest from grub menu.

Comment: I don't know What is a busybox shell. I'll try to test hardware from uefi. Thanks.